# Use values from int[] in SQL statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, sql-injection

I have the following SQL statement that I want to run:

```
string sql = @"DECLARE @a udt;" +
              "INSERT INTO @a (id) VALUES @params;";
```

I have the following array of integers:

```
int[] array1 = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
```

It is important to not that the above array size is dynamic in my program.

I would like to add the values from the array to the `@params` in the SQL statement so that the SQL being executed in the `SqlCommand` looks like this:

```
sql = @"DECLARE @a udt;" +
       "INSERT INTO @a (id) VALUES (10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60);" +
       "EXEC sp @a;";
```

I have tried the following amongst others and keep getting exceptions:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

for (int i = 0; i < array1.Count; i++)
{
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@params" , array1[i]);
}

con.open().
cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

May somebody please explain what I am doing wrong.  I also need to make sure to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: You can't do that, basically. You will have to generate the SQL dynamically, or execute the same (single) insert multiple times with different parameter values.

Comment: @Blorgbeard could I do something like `...VALUES @param1, @param2...`  instead of `...VALUES (10), (20)...` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run the insert X number of times?

Comment: @Ron Beyer no...but how would I do that with the `DECLARE @a udt;` there?

Comment: @JeffOrris yes you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the Int array to format according to `@params` parameter:

```
int[] intArr = { 10, 20, 30 };
string intStr = string.Join(",", intArr.Select(i => "(" + i.ToString() + ")"));
```

`intStr` is in the form `(10),(20),(30)` which you pass to sql. Create dynamic statement and execute it.

```
-- declared here for sample
declare @params varchar(50) = '(10),(20),(30)'

declare @sql varchar(max) = 
    'declare @a table (id int)' + ';' +
    'insert into @a (id) values ' + @params + ';' +
    'exec sp @a'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Will this prevent sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

You are close with your solution, but you need to explicitly reference each array index parameter in the sql string. eg:

```
    List<int> tests = new List<int>() { 10, 11, 12};
    var command = new MySqlCommand();
    List<string> parameterNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.Count; i++)
    {
            string parameterName = String.Format("@test{0}", i);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, tests[i]);
            parameterNames.Add("(" + parameterName + ")");
    }
    string insertSql = @"insert into test(id) values {0}";
    command.CommandText = String.Format(insertSql, String.Join(", ", parameterNames));
    command.Connection = connection;

    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The resulting sql command text will be:

```
"insert into test(id) values (@test0), (@test1), (@test2)"
```

Comment: Why to loop when it can be done in single statement. See my answer.

Comment: Problem with this approach is, that You can not have more than 2100 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generate dynamic SQL for your values clause.  This will cause some performance overhead depending on how often this code is run due to poor plan cache reuse.

I would pass the array in as a delimited string to the procedure and use a SQL string splitter to convert the string into a table.  This allows you to pass in a single parameter to the procedure and possibly bypass the UDT.

There are a variety of string splitters available with a web search.  Any you find that use a loop would be slow, but would work.  I personally prefer Jeff Moden's inline table valued function [[DelimitedSplit8K]](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) (requires free signup, but I think it is well worth it) which is probably the fastest TSQL string splitter.

Usage with any splitter would be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @a udt;
INSERT INTO @a([id])
SELECT [Item]
FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@params)
```

This would convert {10,20,30,40,50,60} to a table with one value per row.

Another usage is for joining:

```
SELECT 
    [col1],
    [col2],
    [ItemNumber] -- position in array
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] A
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@params) B
ON       A.[col3] = B.[Item] -- join on array value
```

Comment: Another Split function - http://dotnetprof.blogspot.in/2012/08/split-function-sql.html